# Next.js conditional style

Tags: css, next.js

I want to make a link active if the pathname matches its href.

```
function Component() {
 const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
      <div className="links">
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        <Link href="/store" className={`${pathname === this.href && "active"}`} >Store</Link>
        <Link href="/actors">Actors</Link>
      </div>
 )}
```

That's what I tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. Can I do something like that?

Comment: Where is `this.href` defined/assigned?

Comment: @Wing I would like to get href of that particular Link ("/store") but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: If you are using the app router directory of the new version of NextJS 13+, you should be able to use the usePathname hook to get the URL. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname. Also because this is a hook, it means you won't be able to use it as a ServerSide component, so make sure to use 'use client' on top of your file to specify that is a client side component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to what Rao Asim said. to avoid repeating make them as an array then [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array.

```
function Component() {
 const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
      <div className="links">
        {[
          { label: "Home", href: "/" },
          { label: "Store", href: "/store" },
          { label: "Actors", href: "/actors" },
        ].map(({label, href}) => (
          <Link 
            key={label} 
            href={href}
            className={pathname === href ? "active" : ""}
           >{label}</Link>
        ))}
      </div>
 )}
```

For better readability, you can move the array declaration out of the JSX:

```
function Component() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const navElements = [
    { label: "Home", href: "/" },
    { label: "Store", href: "/store" },
    { label: "Actors", href: "/actors" },
  ]

  return (
      <div className="links">
        {navElements.map(({label, href}) => (
          <Link 
            key={label} 
            href={href}
            className={pathname === href ? "active" : ""}
           >{label}</Link>
        ))}
      </div>
 )}
```

Comment: Thank you, figured it out on my own and did exactly that. I think that's the best solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use **this** in functional components that is only accessible in class components. And to achieve that you want, you would simply have to write it manually, like:

```
<Link href="/store" className={`${pathname === "/store" ? "active":""}`} >Store</Link>
```

Also don't use **&&** in className, cause it would add false in your className if your condition is false, so instead add ternary operator with "" in false condition.

Comment: You'd also be able to stop wrapping the entire ternary in template literals.